# How to horizontaly scale graphana?

Tags: grafana, alerts, horizontal-scaling

I want to build a stock monitoring system, it will be only for a 100-200 stocks. Now the system needs to be able to trigger alerts for the users.
Initially I want to have grafana with Prometheus or other db. Grafana can handle the alerts independently of the db, but I need a way to scale grafana horizontally as a lot of users will have a lot of alerts. Ideally I would split the alerts dynamically between grafana instances so depending on how many grafana instances are there they can agree and share the instances. Is there some way to configure grafana how I have described? If no what to you suggest for dynamically managing alerts so they can be scaled. I just want to be able to use as much as possible ready services with out developing something on my own.
Any suggestions?